# Can't play games with .ogg files

Tags: sound, games

I just recently compiled Etterna and downloaded a few songs. I could play the songs, but the actual music wouldn't play. I've also tried Puyo Puyo VS (you can import .ogg files to play in the background), and the music wouldn't play. After some research, I realized that I couldn't play any .ogg files. Here's all of the information I could gather (not much, because I'm pretty new to Ubuntu and Linux in general):

Output Device: Headphones - Built-in Audio

Packages that are somewhat related to ogg:
libogg-dev:amd64
libogg0:amd64
libogg0:i386
libvorbis-dev:amd64
libvorbis0a:amd64
libvorbis0a:i386
libvorbisenc2:amd64
libvorbisenc2:i386
libvorbisfile3:amd64
vorbis-tools

Etterna command line:

```
ALSA: Advanced Linux Sound Architecture Driver Version k5.4.0-58-generic.
ALSA Driver: 0: HDA Intel MID [MID], device 0: 92HD75B3X5 Analog [92HD75B3X5 Analog], 0/1 subdevices avail
ALSA Driver: 0: HDA Intel MID [MID], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0], 1/1 subdevices avail
ALSA: dsnd_pcm_hw_params_set_access: Invalid argument
Couldn't load driver ALSA-sw: SetHWParams failed
Couldn't load driver OSS: RageSoundDriver_OSS: Couldn't open /dev/dsp: No such file or directory
```

Sorry if I did anything wrong, or if I'm just not realizing something super obvious. Again, I'm new to Linux and Ubuntu, and any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

it seems it is looking for devices from opensoundsystem (OSS). this was the predecessor from alsa.  If pulseaudio is in use start your programm with

[padsp](https://linux.die.net/man/1/padsp)

Maybe you have to install

```
pulseaudio-utils
```

first.